# how to make reference to a model from another api

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api2

i'm making a app in asp.net webapi dividing the modules in diferents webapi projects. I have a model in one project that make reference to another model in another project. Is there a way to make this reference without recreate this referenced Model or make reference to this dll thinking in the possibility to change this api tecnology?

sorry for the bad english

My Example:

**project baseapi**
Model Client

```
projet baseapi

model Client

publi class Client {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get;set; }
}

project invoiceapi

Model Invoice

public class Invoice {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Unless you want to replicate same objects in both projects (you don't need to do it manually) you may/should move your _shared_ model into a third DLL.

Comment: Yes, Create a new project (maybe APIModel) of Class library type and then reference to this project in other two. It is best practice as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments already.
You shoul move your shared model into another assembly and reference that, in the new project.

1. Create a class library in a different project
2. Add the shared models
3. Build
4. Reference dll, where needed

Comment: Thanks for the help, and if i'm using a ODataController controller and want to include the Client.
example : localhost:3112/api/invoice(1)?$expand=Client.... in this case i have to replicate the Client controller with the get verbs.... is that?

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, Yes. You would have to replicate the client controller as this is a presentation layer implementation detail